# Python script with VPN to AWS Lambda on Cron Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, vpn

I am very new to AWS and their services but I need to run some of  my python scripts (which works with my organization vpn turned on only) on cronjob every day and seems that AWS Lambda can really help.
Is there any tutorial how to put python code from gitlab to AWS Lambda, create a VPN connection and set up the cron job for this ? I'm a little bit stuck with the documentation, so I'd appreciate any advices. Tnx!

Comment: Is the question really about how to create a Lambda function and have it run at a specific time each day? Creating a Lambda function in Python is quite straightforward. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html You could use a CLoudWatch alarm to trigger the function at specific intervals.

Comment: Here are some links on how to setup events using CloudWatch https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/index.html

Comment: @KelvinLawrence but how can I deploy my code from git to Lambda ?

Comment: Here is a post that describes one way https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-github-actions-to-deploy-serverless-applications/